# - Restcomm Olympus WebRTC WSS error,

Tags: restcomm

We are trying to use RESTCOMM OLYMPUS by making few customizations as part of our application.  The main customization is that we have deployed OLYMPUS war on our Apache TOmcat web server and the OUTBOUND PROXY is properly pointed to the same server where RESTCOMM is running.

So far all is good, but recently we got the issue that "getUserMedia()" deprecation issue because of insecure origin issue by chromium fix.
So, it means we need to use HTTPS and WSS.  I can see that just around 7 days back OLYMPUS code has been updated on GITHUB to use WSS if HTTPS has been used in browser location bar.
So first we have installed self signed CERT and enabled SLL config on TOMCAT so that our customized OLYMPUS UI is accessed via https from Tomcat.  And then we used WSS protocol to connect to OUTBOUND PROXY.  Bt we got the below error

"WebSocket connection to 'wss:/:5082/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::**ERR_TIMED_OUT**
WSMessageChannel:createWebSocket(): websocket connection has failed:[object Event]"

Then we thought that in addition to TOMCAT ( where WAR is deployed) we need to install self singed cert and SSL config on RESTCOMM as well. So we did it by following http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-enable-https-secure-connector-on-jboss-as-7-or-eap-6/ and also  we have used **WSS**  protocol.

But this time also we got the error but with a different error code though
"WebSocket connection to 'wss:/:5083/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::**ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**
WSMessageChannel:createWebSocket(): websocket connection has failed:[object Event]"

Can i request the forums to explain if we are missing any thin here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok so where is your RestComm server running? Is it AMI, docker image or zip bundle?

Best regards, Antonis Tsakiridis

Comment: Its a zip bundle we have installed on our UBUNTU server.
Btw we also have followed your response to similar question(https://github.com/Mobicents/olympus/issues/13) i.e. updating the JAIN configuration by updating the Edit $RESTCOMM/standalone/configuration/mss-sip-stack.properties

But still no luck and  we are facing below error WebSocket connection to 'wss://OUR SERVER IP:5083/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled jain-sip.js:25466 WSMessageChannel:createWebSocket(): websocket connection has failed:[object Event]
In fact we have tried both ports 5082 and 5083 and no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the mobicents RestComm docker image instead of using the zip bundle, because for docker image all settings are handled automatically and https/wss should work out of the box. Here are some quick steps to get you started:

- Install docker in your Ubuntu if not already there
- Download RestComm docker image:

  $ docker pull mobicents/restcomm:latest
- Start docker image:

  $ docker run -e SECURE="true" -e SSL_MODE="allowall" -e USE_STANDARD_PORTS="true" -e VOICERSS_KEY="VOICERSS_KEY_HERE" --name=restcomm -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp mobicents/restcomm:latest

Now you should be able to reach your RestComm instance Admin UI at:

`https://<host ip address>/`

Make sure that you don't have any servers running in your host at the ports used by the docker container above, or you'll have to use different ports (please refer to the docker hub page for such options)

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10619738)

Comment: You 're  right, I fixed that and provided a comment to the answer above. Then after the comment was responded to I answered

Comment: We have managed to resolve the issue of WSS error get HTTPS working using ZIP bundle.  But for this, in addition to following instruction as per the "http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-enable-https-secure-connector-on-jboss-as-7-or-eap-6/"  we also had to do the SSL config in STANDALONE.XMl as per the link https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide.    Then we are able to resolve WSS error.  But i see your point to use DOCKER as i think we don't have to do many so many config changes ourselves,as docker will handle it out of the box.  We will try that also.

Comment: Right, docker hides the complexity in configuration. Please let me know if you have any issues with it